# Android read xml from url cut-off

Tags: android, xml, facebook, httpurlconnection

I have an app that takes the xml from a facebook page. The problem is that this part is missing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0"
      xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
      xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    >
  <channel>
    <title>Ð¡Ñ‚ÐµÐ½Ð°Ñ‚Ð° Ð½Ð° Interesting Engineering</title>
    <link>https://www.facebook.com/</link>
    <description>Ð¡Ñ‚ÐµÐ½Ð°Ñ‚Ð° Ð½Ð° Interesting Engineering</description>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <category domain="Facebook">PageSyndicationFeed</category>
    <generator>Facebook Syndication</generator><docs>http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification</docs>
    <lastBuildDate>Tue, 22 Jul 2014 10:00:01 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <webMaster>webmaster@facebook.com</webMaster>
    <item>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">www.facebook.com/notification/9433896181aa13927fc
```

This is the beginning of the xml. 
Here is how I get it:

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            URL url;
            String pageXML = ""; 
            try {
                url = new URL(pageUrl);

                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                streamToString(in);

                Log.i("", pageXML);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void streamToString(InputStream in) throws IOException {
            StringBuilder inputStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                inputStringBuilder.append(line);
                inputStringBuilder.append('\n');
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }

            pageXML = inputStringBuilder.toString();

            Log.i("", pageXML);
            write("interesting_engineering", pageXML);
        }
```

Do you have any idea where could be the problem?
[This](https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=139188202817559) is the url where I take the xml from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fount the problem. There was a part in my code (which I deleted here) that was messing up the things. This was causing the problem:

```
        InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

        int data = isw.read();

        //This line is correct
        streamToString(in);

        while (data != -1) {
            char current = (char) data;
            data = isw.read();
        }
```